# How to apply quantum operators for a system with forbidden states?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators

Lets say I have an operator given by:
$$\hat{A}|n\rangle=|n+1\rangle$$  where $n$=integer

and another operator given by:
$$\hat{B}|n\rangle=|n-1\rangle$$

Now let's suppose for my case states $|n\rangle$ where $n$ > 2 are forbidden (which means we need to put it zero).

Now which one of these are correct $$\hat{B}\hat{A}|2\rangle=\hat{B}|3\rangle=\hat{B}*0=0$$

or

$$\hat{B}\hat{A}|2\rangle=\hat{B}|3\rangle=|2\rangle$$

Edit: Adding information about my system after suggestion in a comment

The system is a cavity filled with a laser input that drives a mechanical oscillator. At the low temperature and driving conditions, we consider a basis state $|m,n\rangle$ with $m,n$  are photon and phonon numbers respectively and truncate it according to the condition $m+n< 3$ as:
$$|\Psi\rangle=C_{00}|0,0\rangle+C_{01}|0,1\rangle+C_{10}|1,0\rangle ......C_{03}|0,3\rangle+C_{30}|3,0\rangle$$

Now my Hamiltonian has in an operator term of the form $\hat{B}\hat{A}$ for the photon such that when it gets applied to the $C_{30}|3,0\rangle$ term of
the above wavefunction it gives:

$$\hat{B}\hat{A}|3,0\rangle=\hat{B}|4,0\rangle$$

What will this give?

Can I now operate $\hat{B}$ on this "forbidden" state to get back the allowed $|3,0\rangle$ state or should directly put it equal to zero since the operator is trying to operate on a forbidden state?

I have gotten two contradictory answers and adopting one from the other causes a difference in the answer. Which one is correct or rather which is more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the higher order are truncated, this truncation is an approximation. Those states if higher occupation numbers is not forbidden, but is neglected. For this truncaiton to be meaningful, the probability of higher-occupation-number states are rarely appeared, either tatical options should be ok. Simply two methods subjected to the truncation approximation.

I prefer to adopt the method
$$ \hat{B}\hat{A}|3,0\rangle=\hat{B}|4,0\rangle = |3,0\rangle $$

The $|4,0\rangle$ is a transient virtual state, and the result does not violate the order of truncation.

Comment: These 2 cases cause a sufficient difference in the answers. I have done the calculations using both the cases and answers differ. Also, your answer is in contrast to Global's answer.

Comment: Also, can this be a choice of "preference"  since the answers and the corresponding graphs clearly differ for *the chosen parameters*. The graphs can be made to match to each other with manipulations with the parameters. So, I guess I should just adopt the one where I get the desired graph for my parameters? Is this correct?

Comment: 1. I don't buy the global answer for this kind of problem. 2. If there are consequently different in these two methods, then you are adopting a poor truncation. You have bigger trouble in defending your choice of a poor truncation. 3. Sometimes, we are forced to a small set of bases for the capacity of computation. Under such circumstance, the absolute value is of no meaning, but hopefullym the trend gives some perspectives.

Comment: As long as these two methods are concerned, My suggestion is definitely the better one. Imaging that we want to reduce a 100 x 100 matrice to a stronger coupled 10 x 10 sub-matrix. A device somehow including the effects of the rest 90 dimensions in the elements of the reduced10x10 matrix is usually considered a better approximation, than  complete neglecting the 90 dimensions as they do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the first one is correct. However, if you do not show a $|3\rangle$ state, it will be more clear expression since $n>2$ states are forbidden. There should not be a $|3\rangle$ state.

$\hat{B} \hat{A} |2\rangle = \hat{B} * 0 = 0 $

The expression above seems more clear; I think there may be a definition for the forbidden states such that

$ \hat{A} |2\rangle = 0$

$ \hat{B} |0\rangle = 0$

Edit:

As a reply to you edit;
Since $|4,0\rangle$ state is forbidden, $\hat{A}|3,0\rangle$ should result in zero (guessing that $\hat{A}$ changes quantum number $m$, and $\hat{B}$ changes quantum number $n$), and again you can come with a definition of those forbidden states as

$\hat{A}|m,n\rangle=0$ if $m+n \geq 3$

$\hat{B}|m,n\rangle=0$ if $n = 0$

Comment: I have added an edit.

Comment: Will this apply there too?

Comment: For that basis, the answer is yes. I also added the answer as an edit.

Comment: What about ytlu's answer? He gives an answer contradictory to yours.

Comment: The states $m+n > 3$ is not forbidden, They are truncated.. Meaning that they are dropped as an approximation for the simplicity of computation.

Comment: I treated them like in the case of occupation numbers of electrons (only two electrons per site, spin up and down, and more than two electrons are forbidden due to Pauli exclusion principle). My answer is more like theoretical, and I considered the states as exactly 'forbidden'. In practice, you may be right ytlu.